# Chrome Extension: How to manipulate browser_action.default_popup DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

For some reason, when i try to access the DOM of the `default_popup` on a `browser_action`, I can't... No js errors, it just seems like the script is running in a different context than i expected it to. 
Here are the relevant code sections from `manifest.json`, `browser_action.html` & `browser_action.js`

manifest.json:

```
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/icon.png",
    "default_title": "title goes here",
    "default_popup": "src/browser_action/browser_action.html"
  },
```

browser_action.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="browser_action.js"></script>
<div id="mainPopup">
    <h1 id="title">Main Title</h1>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/700x350" alt="chart" id="chart" />
</div>
```

browser_action.js:

```
(function(){
  var $title = $('#title');
  console.log($title.length); // 0
})();
```

Comment: Rightclick the popup, then `Inspect` to show its devtools console. [Google Chrome / Firefox do not see extension output in console](//stackoverflow.com/a/38920982)

Comment: Thanks, already did that (notice the console.log in the question, and its result...). The problem was that when the script was executed, the DOM wasn't ready yet...

Comment: Ah, that `// 0` comment... Next time write it in a separate block under the code to make it explicit and obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait for the DOM to prepare itself:

```
$(function() {
var $title = $('#title');
  console.log($title.length);

});
```

Alternatively, move your script file down:

```
<div id="mainPopup">
    <h1 id="title">Main Title</h1>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/700x350" alt="chart" id="chart" />
</div>

...
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="browser_action.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Of course!!! I was looking for a solution so hard that i missed on the "DOM Ready" part... Thanks!

Comment: Alternatively, use the defer script attribute and place them in the head.